# Usage of thanks to other

Tags: grammar

Once I want to show my expression to thank, can we use only one word "Thank" instead of "Thanks"?

Answer (score 1):

No, not by itself, as a gesture of gratitude or acknowlegement.  Also requiring the plural: congratulations, commiserations, condolences, felicitations.

'Thank' singular, must be followed by 'you' and indeed, is often rendered as a single word 'thankyou'. As a response, 'Thank you' is more formal, respectful and impersonal than 'Thanks'.  'Thanks' would sound cheeky if, eg, someone important was pinning a medal on you or conferring a blessing.